# When writing out a phone conversation can you use multiple capitals in a row?

Tags: conversation

When writing out a phone conversation for the purpose of transcription or translation, is it correct to write:

1) Hey, Hi, Well... 
OR
2) Hey, hi, well...

I personally think 2, but others disagree... so just wanted to check.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you write your example with commas, you're treating the three words like one sentence:

> Hey, hi, well...

Typically, you don't capitalize words in the middle of a sentence unless (for example) they're proper nouns.  That means the following is strange:

> Hey, Hi, Well...

You would not typically capitalize *hi* or *well* in this example.

Answer (score 0):

2) **would be correct if "Hey, hi, well..." is all from the same person. EG:**

a: Hey, hi, well I have a question.

b: Hey Bob, sure, what's up?

a: I think I'm in love with your sister.

b: Oh. That's unexpected. You know she's married, right?

*pause*

b: You didn't know she was married. Well, that's awkward.

---

**If each alternating word is by someone else, then (as shown above) each word (sentence) should be on its own line, with proper (assumed) punctuation. EG**

a: Hey.

b: Hi.

a: Well...

Comment: It is the first case, where one person is speaking, and I have been changing it when I've been editing the conversations to #2.